# Generating Crystal Report via PHP Hangs

Tags: php, iis, crystal-reports

I'm trying to generate a crystal report using a php script. The script seems to hang just after ReadRecords(); No error message is generated in the log file. Am I doing somethign wrong?

```
$my_report = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\mamobile\\reports\\invoice.rpt";
$my_pdf = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\mamobile\\reports\\test.pdf";

$ObjectFactory = new COM("CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1");

$crapp = $ObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalDesignRuntime.Application.11");

$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($my_report, 1);

$creport->EnableParameterPrompting = 0;

$creport->DiscardSavedData;
$creport->ReadRecords();

$creport->FormulaSyntax = 0;
$creport->RecordSelectionFormula = "{invoice.invoiceid} = 20070128114815";

$creport->ExportOptions->DiskFileName = $my_pdf;
$creport->ExportOptions->FormatType = 31;
$creport->ExportOptions->DestinationType=1;
$creport->Export(false);

$creport = null;
$crapp = null;
$ObjectFactory = null;
```

A similar version of this code works for a different report.

```
$my_report = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\mamobile\\reports\\" . $name;
$my_pdf = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\mamobile\\reports\\test.pdf";

$ObjectFactory = new COM("CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1");

$crapp = $ObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalDesignRuntime.Application.11");

$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($my_report, 1);

$creport->EnableParameterPrompting = 0;

$creport->DiscardSavedData;
$creport->ReadRecords();

$creport->ExportOptions->DiskFileName = $my_pdf;
$creport->ExportOptions->FormatType = 31;
$creport->ExportOptions->DestinationType=1;
$creport->Export(false);

$creport = null;
$crapp = null;
$ObjectFactory = null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what fixed my problem.

```
$my_report = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\mamobile\\reports\\invoice.rpt";
$my_pdf = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\mamobile\\reports\\test.pdf";

$ObjectFactory = new COM("CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1");

$crapp = $ObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application.11");

$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($my_report, 1);

$creport->EnableParameterPrompting = 0;
$creport->FormulaSyntax = 0;


$creport->DiscardSavedData();
$creport->RecordSelectionFormula = "{invoice.invoiceid} = 20070128114815";
$creport->ReadRecords();

$creport->ExportOptions->DiskFileName = $my_pdf;
$creport->ExportOptions->FormatType = 31;
$creport->ExportOptions->DestinationType=1;
$creport->Export(false);

$creport = null;
$crapp = null;
$ObjectFactory = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. You got stung by the same SO question i did - CrystalRuntime, not CrystalDesignRuntime

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `\\`
2. You are calling `$creport->DiscardSavedData` - if this is a variable, it does nothing. If it is a function-call, it should be `$creport->DiscardSavedData()`.
3. try these settings at the beginning of your script:

   ```
   ini_set('error_reporting', -1); # displays all errors
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);   # reports errors to browser/console
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did manage to figure it out. But I will also play with these settings :)